# ¿Cómo arrastrar un valor para que se incremente un correlativo hasta la siguiente fila llena y esta haga lo mismo en VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Tengo el valor A1 como 300004-1 que al arrastrarlo hasta A4 queda como 300004-4 y el valor de A5 es 300006-1 y este al arrastrarlo con el mouse llega a A7 con 300006-3 y en A8 continua con el valor 300007-1 y así. Quisiera saber qué formula se usa para arrastrar esos valores y den el valor correlativo hasta la siguiente celda.

He usado:

```
Range("A1:A9684").Select

For Each cell In Selection

If cell.value="" Then

cell.Value=cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Pero solo me copia los mismos valores hasta la siguiente y no se arrastra con los correlativos de la derecha después del guión.

¿Qué función o fórmula VBA podría usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que detectar las zonas en blanco y entonces irlas rellenando según el patrón de la celda superior a las zonas en blanco.

En mi ejemplo solo estoy trabajando con el rango A1:a12 pero podría servirte para 9000 filas perfectamente.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim CeldasenBlanco As Range
Dim TopCelda As Range
Dim BottomCelda As Range


Set CeldasenBlanco = Range("A1:A12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'seleccionamos solo celdas en blanco

MiMatriz = Split(CeldasenBlanco.Address, ",") 'matriz con las direcciones de las zonas a rellenar

For i = LBound(MiMatriz) To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    Set TopCelda = Range(MiMatriz(i)).Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0) 'la celda con el patrón
    Set BottomCelda = Range(MiMatriz(i)).Cells(Range(MiMatriz(i)).Cells.Count, 1) ' la última celda en blanco de ese patrón
    TopCelda.AutoFill Destination:=Range(TopCelda.Address & ":" & BottomCelda.Address), Type:=xlFillDefault 'rellenamos
Next i

Erase MiMatriz
Set TopCelda = Nothing
Set BottomCelda = Nothing
Set CeldasenBlanco = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Alguien puede decirme el por qué del voto negativo?

Comment: A mi me ha extrañado nada más entrar a la respuesta... Vaya tela votar negativamente a una respuesta totalmente válida.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funcionó.
Lamento que te hayan puesto voto negativo, demora mucho en aparecerme las notificaciones en el correo por eso demoré en responder.

Comment: Una última consulta sobre tu código. Le puse en A1 el valor de 300004-1, en A4 300007-1, en A7 300010-1, en A9 300023-1, en A13 300044-1 y en A18 tipeé la palabra "NADA". ¿Solo sigue patrones con el mismo formato de número y no acepta otro distinto como la palabra "NADA"?

Comment: La última celda de la selección tiene que tener algo para que detecte la zona en blanco. Por ejemplo, si especificas el área A1:A25, la A25 no puede estar vacía